# KeyEvent#consume() method

Tags: java

Could any one explain what is consume() method and its purpose since I couldn't find much relevant information of it on the net? (example might be the best for a novice like me)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume%28%29

Comment: Yes I don't know how to understand correctly the phrase "Consumes this event so that it will not be processed in the default manner by the source which originated it."

Answer (score 1):

The `consume` method marks the event as processed. Typically this is executed from your program code when you've chosen to act upon the input, e.g. when you wish to prevent a text input from receiving the key stroke.

Or, to take the example given in the Javadocs:

> [The `consume` method] allows listeners and component subclasses to "consume" the event so that the source will not process them in their default manner. For example, consuming `mousePressed` events on a `Button` component will prevent the `Button` from being activated.

Comment: what's going to happen if i consume key event in keyPressed() method?

Comment: Are you referring to a [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html)? Added to what object?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you playing a Game FIFA for example your team is South Africa playing Russia .In normal circumstances if am marking a Russian player and l press key T in instance ,it will invoke a SlideTackle() ,sliding tackling function on the Russian player .

But what if l want to only make it possible that a sliding tackle can only occur whilst they is a opponent player near only that's when l will call consume() method so that the SlidingTackle() function doesn't respond to key press T when Russian opponent is not close .

That's how best l understood